# How to return a hex value after converting it from a string

Tags: c++, binary, hex, strtol

I am trying to return a hex value inside this method. not sure where I'm going wrong. not sure how put the value into hex without using cout. have not been able to find a solution. Input value is always going to be 32 bits long

its like i want to return `hex << x` but thats not an option.

```
string StringToHex (myInstruction* RealList, int Pos)
{
    string result = "11111111110000000000110011001100";
    unsigned long x = strtoul(result.c_str(), &pEnd, 2);
    cout<< hex << x<<endl;
    return  x;
}
```

Comment: You may use stringstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `stringstream` instead of `cout`.

`cout` is just one special ostream that is created by default and is hooked up to the program's standard output. You can create other ostream objects that write to different things. `std::stringstream` writes to a `std::string` inside it.

```
#include <sstream>

std::string to_hex() {
  unsigned int x = 256;

  std::stringstream s;
  s << std::hex << x;
  return s.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream)

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss<< std::hex << x;
std::string res= ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questinon, you want to return a hex value as a string, rigt? If so, then:

```
std::string intToHexStr (int val)
{
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << hex << val;
    std::string result;
    sstr >> result;
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps!